Gate voltage on a quantum dot device, including the electrodes
I am trying to simulate the effect of a gate voltage on a quantum dot device, including the electrodes. To do so, I am using the method described in the article "Manipulating the voltage drop in graphene nanojunctions using a gate potential," which takes into account open boundary conditions.
First, I calculate the area from the supercell in the electrode's FDF file and then find the ratio of Geometry.Charge/Area. Next, I calculate the area from the supercell in the scattering region's FDF file and ensure that the Geometry.Charge/Area is equal to that of the electrode calculations.
However, when I plot the electrostatic potential, I find a kind of barrier between the electrodes and the scattering region, indicating a change in the doping levels. Is my method correct, or should I do something else?
Thank you in advance for your help.

The electronic gate can be a little problematic when the device region is very different from the electrode region.
However, your approach seems correct.

Determine the charge density of the gate you want to use in the electrode, lets assume it takes up an area of $X$ nm2 and has charge $q$.
Now determine the full area of the device calculations unit cell, lets call this $Y$ nm2. The charge used in the device should then be $q Y/X$.

Since the gate will cause an electric field between the atoms and the charged plane, it becomes vital that the defect in the device region is also screened off towards the electrodes. If you have a very large deviation in the potential drop it may be because your device has much fewer atoms/area than your electrode, if this is the case you should extend your electrode regions in the device calculation to better account for the charge screening towards the electrodes.
Keep increasing until your potential looks ok.
